# Multiple github Webhook bypass

Tags: github, plesk

Im trying to bypass the 20 webhook limitation on github.
I have created a ngrok server to recieve github post requests and send them in the same format back to my multiple endpoints that then pull from github. Is this even possible?

```
from flask import Flask,request,json   
import requests
import json
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    @app.route("/webhook", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def webhook():
            return 'Test post'
            json = request.get_json()
            headers = request.get_header()
            print(hello)
            requests.post("XXX:8443/modules/git/public/web-hweb-hook.php?uuid=1e51f92e-b17e-42df-638d-f", data=json.dumps(json), header=header)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
            app.run(debug=True)
```

Thanks for any help or recommendations

Comment: It's technically possible, but the bigger question is why do you need more then 20 webhooks? You might over thinking the solution to your problem.

Comment: @tj-cappelletti I have multiple websites pulling their source code from a single github repo. I have tried other solutions, such as duplicting them internally.

Comment: You should be using GitHub Actions or some other CI/CD process to pull the source code and deploy the websites. Webhooks, while can be used to deploy websites, really isn't best suited for this.

Comment: Ill look into it. I am using plesk as website manager so I’m pretty limited thanks for the input thoguh.

Comment: Thanks for all the input, after alot of Trial and Error I ended up sticking to a Zapier automation.